# Avoid repetitive code in C++ templated functions

Tags: c++, templates

I have a very limited set of real number types (currently `float` and `double`) that I wish all functions of my math library to be templated over. I expect these to be forward declared in header files:

```
template<typename R> void doA(task_t<R> t, ...);
template<typename R> void doB(task_t<R> t, ...);
template<typename R> void doC(task_t<R> t, ...);
```

implemented in source files:

```
template<typename R> void doA(task_t<R> t, ...) { ... }
template<typename R> void doB(task_t<R> t, ...) { ... }
template<typename R> void doC(task_t<R> t, ...) { ... }
```

and explicitly initialized in those source files:

```
template void doA(task_t<float> t, ...);
template void doB(task_t<float> t, ...);
template void doC(task_t<float> t, ...);

template void doA(task_t<double> t, ...);
template void doB(task_t<double> t, ...);
template void doC(task_t<double> t, ...);
```

Furthermore, a subset of those needs to be offered via a C-compatible header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
using taskr32_t = task_t<float>;
using taskr64_t = task_t<double>;
#else
typedef struct taskr32t *taskr32_t;
typedef struct taskr64t *taskr64_t;
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void doAr32(taskr32_t t, ...);
void doBr32(taskr32_t t, ...);

void doAr64(taskr64_t t, ...);
void doBr64(taskr64_t t, ...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

which I give the simplest possible C++ forwarding implementation:

```
void doAr32(taskr32_t t, ...) { doA<float>(t, ...) };
void doBr32(taskr32_t t, ...) { doB<float>(t, ...) };

void doAr64(taskr64_t t, ...) { doA<double>(t, ...) };
void doBr64(taskr64_t t, ...) { doB<double>(t, ...) };
```

That is already 8 repetitions of the full `doA` function declaration. My question is how I can reduce the amount of repetitions and get a cleaner code with less typing required? For instance, is it possible to do explicitly initialization without repeating the full declaration?

I know that many choose to put template function implementations directly into header files to avoid both forward declaration and explicitly initialization, but the arguments against are:

- I know exactly what types I support and the set is very limited.
- Compile time increases (especially incremental compilations of minor changes).
- Dependencies (doA depends on doB and so forth) becomes harder to maintain without forward declarations.

My best idea so far is just to generate the code concerning explicit instantiation and the C-compatible layer which is where all the annoying repetitions happen. Is that a common/well-seen solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may write a macro which will instantiate your function for all types you want.

See [BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each.html). Sample application to your code can be:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

template <class T> class task_t {};

template<typename R> void doA(task_t<R> t) {}
template<typename R> void doB(task_t<R> t) {}
template<typename R> void doC(task_t<R> t) {}

#define MY_TYPES (int)(float)(double)(bool)

#define INSTANTIATE_FOR_TYPE(r, data, my_type) \
template void doA(task_t<my_type> t); \
template void doB(task_t<my_type> t); \
template void doC(task_t<my_type> t);


BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(INSTANTIATE_FOR_TYPE, _, MY_TYPES)                                                                                                     

int main() {}
```

After compiling one may see doABC instantiated for all types

```
nm a.out | c++filt | grep \ do
000000000040053c W void doA<bool>(task_t<bool>)
0000000000400527 W void doA<double>(task_t<double>)
0000000000400512 W void doA<float>(task_t<float>)
00000000004004fd W void doA<int>(task_t<int>)
0000000000400543 W void doB<bool>(task_t<bool>)
000000000040052e W void doB<double>(task_t<double>)
0000000000400519 W void doB<float>(task_t<float>)
0000000000400504 W void doB<int>(task_t<int>)
000000000040054a W void doC<bool>(task_t<bool>)
0000000000400535 W void doC<double>(task_t<double>)
0000000000400520 W void doC<float>(task_t<float>)
000000000040050b W void doC<int>(task_t<int>)
```